# There's an airfield somewhere in the United States with a metal runway. Where is it?

Tags: airport

Somewhere in the United States, there's an airfield (probably military) with a runway made entirely out of metal.  I've seen the approach plate for it, but I can't remember the identifier.

**What airfield am I thinking of?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are thinking of [Bogue Field (KNJM)](http://skyvector.com/airport/NJM/Bogue-Field-Mcalf-Airport). It is a Marine Corps auxiliary landing field, currently mocked up to look like a carrier deck, and last I heard it was still active and in use to practice carrier landings.

The runway surface is Perforated Steel Planking (PSP - actually I believe the new stuff isn't "steel" anymore but the name remains) - discrete sections that can be laid out to quickly construct temporary landing strips in forward combat zones.

---

A search on AirNav for "pierced steel plaking" came up with a couple more military fields:

[KNXP](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KNXP)   Twentynine Palms SELF Airport (Strategic Expeditionary Landing Field) - 
Twentynine Palms, California, USA

[2CA9](http://www.airnav.com/airport/2CA9)   Castle Dome Army Heliport - 
Yuma Proving Ground (Yuma), Arizona, USA

2CA9 says it's a helipad but it's 3000x65. The rest of the results were all (reasonably sized) helipads.

Comment: if 2CA9 exists, i couldn't find it on gmaps

Comment: you think 2000x72 is reasonable size? "CAUTION: HELICOPTER LZ (HLZ) WHITE RHINO (UAS STRIP 2000' X 72') S OF AND PARALLEL TO RWY 28 IS PRIM FOR TENANT UAS SUPPORT, RSTD TO UAS AND COPTER OPS ONLY"