# What do different runway depictions mean in the Chart Supplement?

Tags: runways, chart-supplement

I cannot find a digital Chart Supplement (AF/D) glossary.

What is the length requirement to depict a runway as a dashed line vs. solid black?

The depiction for [Melbourne, Florida](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1713/afdpdf/SE_120_07DEC2017.pdf) shows one runway with a dashed line and another as solid.

At [JFK](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1713/afdpdf/NE_222_07DEC2017.pdf), all the runways have dashed lines. What do the different depictions mean?

Answer (score 7):

The glossary I'm looking at (page 13 from the current South Central US Chart Supplement) says that that style of dashed line indicates **Runway Centerline Lighting**.  So runways that have the dashed lines have lights on the runway.

The complete chart supplements are available [online](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/) from the FAA, and the glossary for each one is easily found about Page 13 for each section.

Comment: Look at Melbourne Florida’s two larger runways. One is dashed symbol. Other is black. Look at JFK. All runways dashed. What is a “Metal” surface?  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Thanks very much for answering that. I have the AF/D thru Fly Q and Foreflight, but no glossary

Comment: @Rosie for metal surface see [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/826/1696)

Comment: Everything the FAA thinks you need to know about charts is in [FAA Aeronautical Chart User's Guide](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/media/editions/cug-complete.pdf).

Comment: @Gerry: That document does not seem to cover the Chart Supplements (formerly the AF/D or green books).